# Dynamically creating DOM, in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please see the below code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
<div ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(5) track by $index">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="n.firstname">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="n.lastname">
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Query 1: Here, I have passed hard coded 5 in ng-repeat section. Instead of that, I want to pass value of the dropdown, which user will select. Is it possible in angularjs?

Query 2: In those input boxes, I want to give a separate ng-model name. eg. first firstname ng-model would be firstname1. 2nd row ng-model would be firstname2. If its possible, then I can directly map these models, to my oracle database columns. But I am not getting any way to resolve these situation. Is it possible in angular js?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  $scope.selectedName = 0;
  $scope.NameDetail = [];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
<div ng-repeat="n in names | limitTo : selectedName track by $index">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="NameDetail[n].firstname">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="NameDetail[n].lastname">    
</div>
{{NameDetail}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. I need something like this. Only thing, I want to change here is the last line - {{NameDetail}} .... In this line you are showing, the whole object....Let's say I want to view only the value of firstname of first and second row? How to do that?

Comment: You have used "NameDetail[n].firstname" in ng-model...But n is not replaced here...What I want is, if I run this - {{NameDetail1.firstname}}, it will give the first row textbox value. if I run this - {{NameDetail2.firstname}} - it should give the value of 2nd row firstname textbox value. I am not seeing any use of using 'n' in the model name. Please let me know,if you are not clear with my query.

Comment: actually i am not clear with your query and yes we cant use dynamic modal name like NameDetail1.FirstName to store values.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I tried to create dynamic model name a lot. But it seems like angularjs doesn't have that feature.